# Keep the undo/redo history after closing and reopening a project

Tags: visual-studio, undo-redo

If I close a VS project and then reopen it, the undo/redo history is lost. Is there any way of storing the undo/redo history, so that I can undo/redo things even after closing the VS?
I have VS 2005. However I would like to know if there is a solution to my problem for any version of VS.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it ...
Visual studio simply doesn't support any kinds of redo undo history stuff after closing application so you better use 3rd party to keep your source safe (eg ... github)